# JPA Hibernate merge performs insert instead of update

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a simple test, where I am trying to update the object, but merge seems to be performing an insert instead of update.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring/app-context.xml","classpath:spring/testdb-context.xml"})
public class UserJPATest {
@Test
public void testUpdate() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("update");

    User entity = ObjectManager.USER_DAO.findById(3L);
    entity.setUsername("harryUpdate");

    ObjectManager.USER_DAO.update(entity);

    User selEntity = ObjectManager.USER_DAO.findById(3L);
    Assert.assertEquals(entity.getUsername(),selEntity.getUsername());
}
```

}

This is my update method

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation= Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public T update(T entity) throws Exception {
    try {
        T merged = entityManager.merge(entity);
        return merged;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Exception(e);
    }
}
```

Update to code

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation= Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public T update(T entity) throws Exception {
    try {
        T merged = null;
        BaseEntity baseEntity = null;
        if(entity instanceof BaseEntity){
            baseEntity = (BaseEntity)entity;
            merged = entityManager.find(entityClass, baseEntity.getId());
        }
        merged = entityManager.merge(entity);
        entityManager.flush();
        return merged;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Exception(e);
    }
}
```

Now I get the following error Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly

Comment: How do you determine that it performs insert?

Comment: I don't **really** like the **REQUIRES_NEW** propagation, you might be creating the entity in a TX and then doing a "merge or update" in a different TX, which doesn't know about the original entity.

Comment: I checked the logs and it tries to do a insert

Comment: To Augusto....that makes sense. I changed the code, but now I get Transaction marked as rollbackonly. I have updated the code above

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had a version column which was not set when seed data was inserted into database. Hence all the problems with update and delete

Comment: Thanks user373201, I had been struggling with this and I came across your suggestion, as soon as I changed the version, it started working as it was suppose to. Thanks.

Comment: version column ,,which one , im also having same issue,i have set all column of database, but it still inserting record instead of updating.help

Comment: i know this is old thread but even today... many developers face same problem....so i am posting, one possible reason for this problem...  http://www.programmingforfuture.com/2011/02/hibernate-merge-may-insert-new-record.html

Comment: more than 10 years after this answer was posted it's still helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Merge will update the row ONLY IF it founds the id in the database, so if you create a new object and forgot to set its ID to the same ID of the desired row, it will try to insert a new one. In case your database table doesn't have any unique field, probably this insert will be successful as there will be no sql error.

I was able to update the desired row once I set the new object with the ID of that row.